# Accessing Azure key vault keys from ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

We are having a requirement to store rsa key in key vault and use it in ADF.
So we saved *.pem file(rsa key) in azure key vault keys. But in ADf we see only the key vault secrets. It dosn't list key vault-keys in ADF.
So how do we access the keys?

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not correct you need to request the private keys from Azure Key Vault as secrets, not keys.

For example, if you upload a certificate (with a private key) to AKV, then you need to retrieve the private key using the GetSecrets API in Azure Key Vault.

If you try to use the more obvious GetCertificate method, then you only get the certificate with its public key. Yes, its odd....

Answer (score 0):

We stored a private key for a SFTP linked service in the Azure Key Vault as a secret. We retrieve it by inputting the secret name.